# How can I concatenate a string within a loop in JSTL/JSP?

Tags: java, string, jsp, loops, concatenation

```
<c:forEach items="${myParams.items}" var="currentItem" varStatus="stat">
  <c:set var="myVar" value="<c:out var="myVar" />" />
</c:forEach>
```

I want to concatenate the values of currentItem.myVar and output it at the end of the loop, problem is I can't figure out how to do this...

(Preferably not using Java)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Perhaps this will work?

```
<c:forEach items="${myParams.items}" var="currentItem" varStatus="stat">
  <c:set var="myVar" value="${stat.first ? '' : myVar} ${currentItem}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: this is ok, except the first value is null

Comment: OK, I added a check to see if it's the first time through the loop. Does that work?

Comment: You can use this same concept to concat a string with a delimiter like  this:  `value="${ids}${stat.first ? '' : ','}${currentItem.id}"`

Answer (score 17):

You're using JSTL 2.0 right?  You don't need to put `<c:out/>` around all variables. Have you tried something like this?

```
<c:forEach items="${myParams.items}" var="currentItem" varStatus="stat">
  <c:set var="myVar" value="${myVar}${currentItem}" />
</c:forEach>
```

**Edit**: Beaten by the above

Comment: this is ok, except the first value is null =/

Comment: first value null: Just do another c:set outside of the loop to initialize myVar.

Comment: Then perhaps wrap the set tag in an if? <c:if test="${not empty currentItem}"/> ... </c:if>?

Comment: EL doesn't evaluate `null` values as a `"null"` string. The problem lies somewhere else. It is apparently incorrectly been set as a `"null"` string.

Comment: Thanks  Ben and @Subin,

Its saved a lot of mine time.

Answer (score 4):

Is JSTL's `join()`, what you searched for?

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="${fn:join(myParams.items, ' ')}" />
```

Answer (score -6):

define a String variable using the JSP tags

```
<%!
String test = new String();
%>
```

then refer to that variable in your loop as

```
<c:forEach items="${myParams.items}" var="currentItem" varStatus="stat">
test+= whaterver_value
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Using Java isn't the way to go with this, I think I need to use JSTL

Comment: almost -1 for new String(). How about ""?

Comment: Thilo yeah, I understand for new String(). My mistake!