# Accessing HashMap in EL with string + int key

Tags: jstl, el

Is there a way to access HashMap element in EL with key which is concatenation of String and int value. Something like this:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="5" var="current">
   <c:out value="${myHashMap['elem-' + current]}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Related: [How can I concatenate a string within a loop in JSTL/JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code can accomplish desired behavior

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="5" var="current">
   <c:set var="key" value="elem-${current}" />
   <c:out value="${myHashMap[key]}"/>
</c:forEach>
```