# How do I concatenate a list of values in JSTL into a single JSTL var?

Tags: spring, variables, jstl, string-concatenation

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3.Final and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  On my JSP page, how do I get all the ids of an array into a comma separated string?  I have tried this:

```
<c:forEach var="subject" items="${category.subjects}" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${status.index == 0}">
        <c:set var="cateogrySubjects" value="${subject.id}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${status.index > 0}">
        <c:set var="categorySubjects" value="${subject.id},${categorySubjects}"/> 
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Unfortunately the last statement printed is always “subj1,subj1” in the array even if the intermediate values are “subj1”, “subj2”, “subj3”, etc.  Any help on concatenating things would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate a String within a loop in JSTL/JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542436/how-can-i-concatenate-a-string-within-a-loop-in-jstl-jsp)

Comment: The reason it isn't the same is he prepends a space upon every iteration of the loop.  I only want to insert a comma for iterations of the loop zero.

Comment: Did you see the comment by Jess on the accepted answer? It's showing how to insert a comma between the values.