# How can I concatenate a string inside loop in JSTL/JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

This question must be  pointed as duplicate , but i tried so much did not get solution.
I am doing

```
 <c:forEach items="${myForm.selectedValue}" var="currentItem" >
      <c:set var="myVar" value="${myVar},${currentItem}" />
    </c:forEach>
```

My output is:-,10,20,30,40
I Require :-10,20,30,40  (As First time myvar is null )
So I can not intilize myVar with anything

And I can not use

```
<c:forEach items="${myForm.selectedValue}" var="currentItem" varStatus="stat">
  <c:set var="myVar" value="${stat.first ? '' : myVar} ${currentItem}" />
</c:forEach>
```

As output required : 10,20,30,40

I chcked

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542436/how-can-i-concatenate-a-string-within-a-loop-in-jstl-jsp
```

Saw accepted answer and read all comment
But did not get what i required

```
P.S :- I am working on JDK1.4 .Apologies thousand time guys , I know this is sin .But I need to modify a very old Project
So please answer as per JDK 1.4 JSTL 1.0 :
```

Comment: Thanks moskito-x it is fine but still first String is ',' , I should have accepted yr answer .Thanks for the help , Thanks a Ton

Comment: how can that be with `<c:if test="${!empty myVar}">` Only if NOT empty then ->`,`<- comes into play !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="${myVar}${empty myVar ? '' : ','}${currentItem}" />
```

TEST
(Sorry) For lack of time, just inserted in my project.

```
<select>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${Friends.rowsByIndex}">
      <option><c:out value="${row[0]}"/> <c:out value="${row[1]}"/></option>
      <c:set var="myVar" value="${myVar}${empty myVar ? '' : ','}${row[1]}" />
</c:forEach>
</select>  
<c:out value="${myVar}"/>
```

Look here on the output next to the select element (Sorry)

[image]

**If the above does not work, this should work in "JSTL1.0"**

```
<c:if test="${!empty myVar}">
  <c:set var="myVar" value="${myVar}," />
</c:if>
<c:set var="myVar" value="${myVar}${currentItem}" />
```

Comment: I already mentioned in above comment that using ternary operator in JSL 1.4 (JSTL1.0) is throwing error            Errror is  'set' / attribute = 'value': An error occurred while parsing custom action attribute "value" with value "${myVar}${empty myVar ? '' : ','}${currentItem[1]}": Encountered "?", expected one of ["}", ".", ">", "gt", "<", "lt", "==", "eq", "<=", "le", ">=", "ge", "!=", "ne", "[", "+", "-", "*", "/", "div", "%", "mod", "and", "&&", "or", "||", ":", "("]      Kinldy suggest as per JDK 1.4